# Stop LyX Outline Pane from switching back to "Table of Contents"

Tags: lyx, labels

Example:

[image]

Once I click on the main text and press "Enter", the Outline Pane automatically switches back to "Table of Contents" (instead of sticking with "Labels and References", which is what I'd like).

How do I stop this?

Comment: Nice question and thanks for including the animated gif. That makes it very clear! I'm not sure why there is a close vote here, but note that questions about LyX are [on topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: By the way, welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in LyX. It is fixed in the development version and will be included in LyX 2.4.0 when it is released (hopefully in a couple of months).

If you are feeling brave, you can help us test the development version to find bugs before it is released. If this interests you, join the [lyx-users](https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc2) mailing list and send an email that you're interested in testing 2.4.0dev.