# Outline windows won't stay on chosen item

Tags: lyx

The Outline window won't stay on Figures or other option in the dropdown menu. It always jump back to Table of Contents automatically, and this makes it inconvenient to check the Figures list.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a problem with your editor, not with TeX itself. What software are you using? Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Is this a LyX related question? If yes, consider adding the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the problem with Lyx version 2.3.7. I find the similar question with this post.
[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702779/stop-lyx-outline-pane-from-switching-back-to-table-of-contents)

And I find this problem already solved in the new developed version 2.4 of Lyx.
Thank you all guys for replying!